# backing up old computer to new one

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, hard-drive

I purchased a new computer with Windows 10 and my current computer has Windows 7.  I was considering putting the old hard drive into the new computer until I found a topic here where it wasn't suggested.

Users mentioned backing up the computer but there was no mention of software so I'm wondering what software do you use to transfer programs and documents from one computer to the next?  Is the success transfer rate lower since it's transferring from a HP Windows 7 to a Cyberpower Windows 10 computer?

I have a WD external drive on the way large enough for a backup file to transfer to the new computer.  Is there a free program that can be used?  My new computer has a SSD which is new to me but I think I'll only upload the previous computer files to the main hard drive. One of my current external WD hard drives has a file labeled "Do your data recovery" but don't know anything about it and that drive doesn't have enough room to do a backup anyway.

Comment: Why were you suggested not to put the old HD in the new machine? Surely it has room for more than 1 drive, can't you just use both?

Comment: I know nothing about the tank (computer) I got and don't want to void the warranty.  I planned on keeping both computers to stream in the future, but it was driving me crazy knowing I'd have to reinstall everything so I looked into transferring the hard drive to the new computer where some had success, others didn't, but apparently I don't have to go to that extent.  There's a method that works in transferring the old hard drive files/programs so I'm looking for a free program that does just that.

Comment: If you really don't want to open your machine for warranty reasons (I can understand you), I think that your best option is to get an external hard drive case; you can connect it from an USB port and you can  move files around without any specific software, it will work like a removable device.

Comment: Anyway, this method will let you transfer files, but with a new OS, you will have to reinstall your programs and apps

Answer (score 0):

We can’t transfer the installed programs from one computer to another easily. You need to install each software and activate them individually on the new Windows 10 computer.

But we can copy and paste general data from the Windows 7 computer to Windows 10 computer directly, this process needs a media, such as an external drive(usb drive) or network connection.

You could copy data to a removable drive, then insert this drive into your new computer, paste data.

Or let these two computer in a same network, share the data that you need to transfer.

Regards

Answer (score -1):

This question is very simple, you have two ways. If you are a desktop, you can plug the old hard drive directly into the new computer, because desktops generally support multiple hard drives. If you are a laptop, you can use AOMEI Partition Assistant to [migrate the operating system from the old hard drive to the hard drive of the new computer](https://www.diskpart.com/windows-10/how-to-copy-windows-10-from-one-computer-to-another-0001.html). And there will be a Universal Restore function to help you solve the problem of not being able to start normally after migration.